# Detect initial position of iOS Device in 3D Space - Core Motion

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion, sensor-fusion

Using Coremotion we can `get the change in position of device using attitude, rotation using gyro`. **But to know the actual position of device in 3D space, we would need the initial position of the device.** So that accordingly the userAcceleration, gyro data could be applied the get new actual position after changes. How to get the initial actual position of device. I want to detect the position like "45 degree tilted in left with face up" or "45 degree tilted in right with rotated at 30 degrees in y axis".

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreMotion accelerometers to estimate the initial position of your device using some equations.

```
let x = data.acceleration.x 
let y = data.acceleration.y
let z = data.acceleration.z

let roll = atan (y / sqrt(pow(x,2.0) + pow(z, 2.0)));
let pitch = atan (x / sqrt(pow(y, 2.0) + pow(z, 2.0)));
let yaw = atan (sqrt(pow(x, 2.0) + pow(z, 2.0))/z);
```

Somehow, the Yaw is still relative to the starting position of your Device. In order to fix that issue, you should look for using the Compass.